# c# Ultratree how to selected child node different parent node

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultratree

i use c# language and Visual studio to make windows application

i need to selected multiple node different parent

i need to do like this

- parent A

  - node 1 <-selected
  - node 2
- parent B

  - node 1
  - node 2 <-selected
- parent C

  - node 1 <-selected
  - node 2

Comment: You can do it by setting it's selection related properties if you are asking about infragistics treeview control

Comment: You need to show the code you have written so far and ask a question on a specific problem you are having.  This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: @NiranjanKala i set selectiontype = extended but ultratree can only mupltple selected same parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these settings:

```
        // Allow the end user to select multiple nodes.
        this.ultraTreeView1.Override.SelectionType = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTree.SelectType.Extended;
        // Allow the end user to select nodes in different levels of the tree.
        this.ultraTreeView1.SelectionBehavior = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTree.SelectionBehavior.ExtendedAcrossCollections;
```

Hope this help..

Comment: Thank you for your help. this code solved my ploblem , I’m very grateful.